# When is a place 'generally accessible'

Tags: austria, local-authorities

In local regulation at a place I wish to wildcamp there is something like this (translated):

> 1) Within the city limits of Werfen, Austria it is not allowed to place tents, trailers. mobile homes etc. for the purpose of sleeping over night in public (generally accessible) places. This does not apply to licensed camp sites

[image]

But now my question is, how is 'generally accessible' defined by law? How could I interpret this? I thought I could reason *a contrario* and say that I'm allowed to place camping gear in places **not** generally accessible (from roads or trails). Is this a valid argument?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, yours is not a valid argument. What is meant by "generally accessible" is public places like plazas, stretches of green by the road, parks, parking lots, etc. The definition is kind of a negative and could be more easily phrased as: "You may camp at A) designated camping areas or B) private places where you are entitled to camp". This means you either have to find a camping area where you pay a fee for a period of time, or you may camp on private grounds that either belong to you, or you have been given explicit permission to camp, say in a private garden or field. Of course this is practically impossible if you don't know anyone in there.

But, the screenshot explicitly restricts this rule with the leading prase "Im Gemeindegebiet" which means if you leave the legal boundaries of Werfen, Salzburg county law applies (Which may or may not be similar).

Disclaimer: While I don't have legal background, I can tell from personal experience that local governments are touchy on this and striking up camp somewhere where you are not allowed to will at least (if detected) require you to leave the premises immediately and the police may charge you with trespassing.